# namespace "std" has no member "variant"

Tags: c++

My code isn't working and I don't know why.  I am on Windows, I'm using the latest version of the G++ compiler, I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and whatever C++ version comes with it.

I tried to have a value that was variant thing but it said that namespace "std" has no member "variant" even after including it

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

int main()
{
    std::variant<int, double> value;

    std::cout << "Hi";

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: So are you using Visual Studio or g++? These are two different compilers.

Comment: You might need to update the project settings to force the compiler to build with at least the C++17 standard. If there's no alternative to select it in the GUI, then add the `/std:c++17` command-line option.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the compiler error, your compiler should have also given you a warning:

```
warning STL4038: The contents of <variant> are available only with C++17 or later.
```

This gives you a clear hint to what the problem is: The `<variant>` header's contents are only available when compiling in C++17 mode. The default on Visual Studio 2022 is C++14, which is too old.

Right-click your project in the Solution Explorer and select *Properties*.

Go to *Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Language* and set *C++ Language Standard* to *ISO C++ 17 Standard (/std:c++17)* or a later standard. Build your program again and everything should compile.